# Categorical data decision tree coded different than the correct one

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, categorical-data

I'm trying to code some example data I got from a course. However, the result I received is different from the course's result.

The data is categorical so I used one hot coder and for the output (playing tennis) I just changed 'no' to 0 and 'yes' to 1

Below you'll find the code I used, the result I received and the result received on the course

This is the code I made

```
import numpy as np 
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import graphviz

# Variable Declaration
X = np.array([["sunny", "sunny", "overcast", "rain", "rain", "rain", "overcast", "sunny", "sunny", "rain", "sunny", "overcast", "overcast", "rain"],["hot", "hot", "hot", "mild", "cool", "cool", "cool", "mild", "cool", "mild", "mild", "mild", "hot", "mild"],["high", "high", "high", "high", "normal", "normal", "normal", "high", "normal", "normal", "normal", "high", "normal", "high"],["weak", "strong", "weak", "weak", "weak", "strong", "strong", "weak", "weak", "weak", "strong", "strong", "weak", "strong"]])
Y = np.array(["no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no"])

X = X.transpose()
Y = Y.transpose()

# Encoding strings into array numbers "one-hit-encoding"
enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(X)

# Categories found in the feature X
#print(enc.categories_)
Xenc = enc.transform(X).toarray()

# Encoding strings into array numbers 
Yenc = Y
Yenc[Yenc == 'no'] = 0
Yenc[Yenc == 'yes'] = 1

# Train the tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3)
clf = clf.fit(Xenc,Yenc)

# plotting the tree
#tree.plot_tree(clf)

feat_name = ['outlook', 'temp', 'humidity', 'wind']

# Retrieve features names
dot_data = export_graphviz(
    clf,
    out_file=None,
    feature_names=enc.get_feature_names(input_features=feat_name)
)

# Plotting the graph
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)
graph.render("tree_plot")
graph

# joining the examples and the features names
list(zip(feat_name, enc.categories_))


# Remplacing the <= sign with the = sign and putting the examples on the other side
import re
new_dot = dot_data
for i, col in enumerate(feat_name):
  for cat in enc.categories_[i]:
    new_dot = re.sub(f"{col}_{cat} <= 0.5", f"{col}={cat}", new_dot)


# Switching the false and true labels    
new_dot = re.sub('labelangle=45, headlabel="True"', 'labelangle=45, headlabel="False"', new_dot)
new_dot = re.sub('labelangle=-45, headlabel="False"', 'labelangle=-45, headlabel="True"', new_dot)

# Plotting the graph using graphviz
graph = graphviz.Source(new_dot)
graph.render("tree_plot")
graph
```

### Here is the result I received

[image]

### This is the received by the course owner

[image]

Comment: In the course owner's tree, you can see split of the categories directky, which is not doable in scikit-learn (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html) Most likely another library was used, or the figure you have is only meant for illustration, because you don't see the split values

Comment: @StupidWolf Well, I believe it's only for demonstration. However, we normally should have the same output aka splits. btw i'm not referring to the split values